# Cannot connect to Azure Virtual Machine Remote Desktop using Parallels Client

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, rdp, parallels

I am on Ubuntu 17.04 and I have installed the latest version of Parallels RAS Client. I am trying to connect to my VM using the credentials in my .rdp file I have downloaded from the Azure dashboard. I keep on getting this error.

```
Code [01/00000001] The specified remote RAS Connection could not be found. Verify that you have typed the correct computer name or IP address, and then try to connect again.
```

So far, I have tried the following:

1) Manually inputting my credentials into the connection settings and trying both ports 3389 and 80.

2) Checking with telnet as outlined here. http://kb.parallels.com/en/123015

No luck with both.

I have resorted to Parallels RAS Client (formerly 2Xrdp) simply because Remmina will not play sound on my machine.